# Evolutionary algorithm

Tags: optimization, algorithms, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

Can someone provide me a good reference for the CMA-ES algorithm? I'm new in the world of optimization and just reading the author reference doesn't help me a lot.
I know the basic idea of a genetic algorithm but this is not enough. Is there anyone who knows about some introductory video lectures about it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any video on this topic but
you may 
 1. check GECCO'2014 tutorial https://www.lri.fr/~hansen/gecco2014-CMA-ES-tutorial.pdf
 2. play with a simplified but still core CMA-ES code in MATLAB 'pure CMA-ES' https://www.lri.fr/~hansen/purecmaes.m
 3. read 'Adaptive Encoding: How to Render Search Coordinate
System Invariant' by N. Hansen, PPSN 2008 (I cannot provide >2 links as a guest)